# Accessing Type T property in the ParameterExpression type Dictionary<string,T>

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees, func

I have expression tree code used for data filtering, till date it was used on a Generic list `List<T>` and following code use to work fine:

```
var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Name");
```

It was easy to create a binary expression as follows and process the result:

```
var constantExpression = Expression.Constant("Jack",typeof(string));

var finalExpression = Expression.Equal(memberExpression,constantExpression);

var resultFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(finalExpression, parameterType).Compile();

// Final Result
sourceList.Where(obj => resultFunc(obj));
```

Here `Name` is a property in `Type T`, as result post Lambda compilation was `Func<T,bool>`, I use to apply the same to the `Where` clause of `IEnumerable` type. Now the underlying system has changed to use the same code on `Dictionary<string,T>`, so all the Type T values in the collection now have a string Key associated and type T is now accessible as a value of dictionary object. Also I am applying on a `IQueryable`, which takes an expression tree the final lambda post compilation at source would be `Func<KeyValuePair<string,T>,bool>`, therefore cannot apply the Value in the final result processing.

Following is the code modification now:

```
var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(KeyValuePair<string,T>), "obj");
```

**Following code fails, since now Name property is in Value of the KeyValuePair and we cannot use it as Type T:**

```
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Name");
```

Any pointer to make it work or any suggestion to set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get Expression for calling ["name"] item this way:

```
var nameProperty= Expression.Call(parameterType, 
       typeof(IDictionary<string, T>).GetMethod("get_Item"), 
       Expression.Constant("Name"));
```

or as:

```
var nameProperty = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Item", 
                         new Expression[] { Expression.Constant("Name") });
```

Both is call of `Item` property

**EDIT** : To get Value from `KeyValuePair` you have to get property Key, compare it with "Name" and a property Value and compare it with value:

```
var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(KeyValuePair<string,T>), "obj");

var value = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Value" );
var key = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Key");

var  eq1 = Expression.Equal(key, Expression.Constant("Name"));
var  eq2 = Expression.Equal(value, constantExpression);
var and = Expression.And(eq1, eq2);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(and, parameterType);
```

Comment: There was mistake in my question, please review it again, I am suppose to supply the KeyValuePair<string,T> instead of Dictionary<string,T>, which is a collection of KeyValue pairs, now can i use the same solution suggested by you, my understanding is Yes

Comment: Also wouldn't there be a way for me to fetch with `Value` property of KeyValue pair instead of using the indexer access, as done using Item array

Comment: Will this access Name property of Type T:

`Expression.Property(parameterType, "Value" )` ?, it is meant for the Value access, which gives whole object

Comment: @MrinalKamboj sorry, i haven't understood first, what the problem is, i updated the answer

Comment: only point you might have missed out is, following code  `Expression.Property(parameterType, "Value")` will provide me a Type T, as its accessing Value property of KV, now I need to further access the Name property on this, so mostly what I need is:
`Expression.Property(value, "Name" )`, to create a final expression, I am testing it. `Name` is not the key for KV, as done in following code:
`Expression.Equal(key, Expression.Constant("Name"))`

Comment: could you update your question with the expression you want to construct. I was thinking, you are looking for something like:  x=>x["Name"]=="Jack"

Comment: That's what I have mentioned in the question,  I need to work with `Type T`, earlier it was simple as T was supplied, now its `KeyValuePair<string,T>`, so earlier code was breaking as I was not fetching the Value in between, your solution is working, thanks